# How to update addresses in SAP business one for sales order?

Tags: c#, sql, sapb1

So I have code which is linked to the SAP Business Partner Master Data which can update the addresses from my visual studio. The hard part is getting the addresses to update for every single sales order. For example

1. Sales order created and has addresses 12345 street

BP master data changed addresses to 54321 street

The sales order doesnt update the addresses unless I create a new sales order

2. sales order created and has addresses 54321 street

This one has the address because I created it after the bp was changed. So is there a way in my code that it not only changes the bp master data but also changes all of the sales orders that were created of that specific address?

As of now I only have code which I can update the business partner master data addresses from my visual studio but not the sales order. So how do i establish the link with the sales order with it as well so it updates the addresses automatically right when i update the bp master data as well?

```
    SELECT        h.DocEntry, h.DocNum, h.CardCode, h.CardName, h.DocDate, h.DocDueDate, ao.StreetS AS [Street in Order], ac.Street AS [Street in Master Data], ao.ZipCodeS AS [ZipCode in Order], ac.ZipCode AS [ZipCode in Master Data], 
                         ao.CityS AS [City in Order], ac.City AS [City in Master Data], ao.CountryS AS [Country in Order], ac.Country AS [Country in Master Data], ac.State AS [State in Master Data], ao.StateS AS [State in Order], 
                         ac.Block AS [Block in Master Data], ao.BlockS AS [Block in Order]
FROM            dbo.ORDR AS h INNER JOIN
                         dbo.RDR12 AS ao ON h.DocEntry = ao.DocEntry INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OCRD AS c ON h.CardCode = c.CardCode INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CRD1 AS ac ON c.CardCode = ac.CardCode AND ao.StreetS <> ac.Street AND ao.ZipCodeS <> ac.ZipCode AND ao.CityS <> ac.City AND ao.CountryS <> ac.Country AND ao.BlockS <> ac.Block AND 
                         ao.StateS <> ac.State
WHERE        (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (h.DocStatus = 'O')
```

This is all I have my code so far
[image]

So essentially I have no idea where and how to start specially when pulling in the queries but Im not sure how to link the bp master data to the sales order that was already created, as it wont update the new addresses even when i press refresh on the sales order.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: check now plsss

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Query to retrieve a list of all the Order DocEntry that you wish to update.

For each item in the List perform a DI-API update on each Sales Order Record.

simple example:

```
// get your list of DocEntry
var listofOrderToUpdate = new List<int>();

var sqlQueryText  = "Select DocEntry From ORDR where CardCode = '123456'";

using (var objSQLconn = new SqlConnection(gstrConnectionStringSAP))
{

    using (var objSQLComm = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryText  objSQLconn))
    {
        objSQLconn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = objSQLComm.ExecuteReader)
        {
            while (reader.Read)
                listofOrderToUpdate.add(reader[0]);
        }
    }
}


SAPbobsCOM.Company objCompany = Application.SBO_Application.Company.GetDICompany;

SAPbobsCOM.Documents objOrder = objCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oOrders);


foreach (var entry in listofOrderToUpdate)
{

    objOrder.GetByKey(entry);
    if (objOrder.DocumentStatus == SAPbobsCOM.BoStatus.bost_Open)
    {

        // shipping Address - Address ID will come from CRD1 Table, or from address Tab of the Business Partner Form 
                objOrder.ShipToCode = "my address ID"

        // billing Address - same for billing address
                objOrder.PayToCode = "my other address ID"    


        var ret = objOrder.Update;

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(objCompany.GetLastErrorDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Updated order: " + entry.ToString());
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: So im still new to sql but I have this when i pull the query
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT        Address2, DocNum, ShipToCode FROM dbo.ORDR";
So how do i link the bp data to the old so's so it gets updated as well?

Comment: Do you need to update every Sales Order for That specific Business Partner, or only the Sales Orders that have the Old Address?

Comment: i have updated the answer to collect a list of Sales Order DocEntry from the Matching Business Partner.

Comment: I need to update every OPEN sales order for that specific business partner if it was changed etc. So if i changed the address in the business partner for company name xyz, in the sales order for the company name xyz it should change for open sales orders. When I use your code it states application does not contain a definition for sbo_application and sapbobcom does not exist in current context. Im not sure how to run the query for it either

Comment: you say you have code that will update the Business Partner Address, please add this code to your question. SAP B1 cannot be updated through direct sql commands to the Database  , it needs to be done via DI-API.

Comment: So when i add the code in, it says application does not contain a definition for sbo application and listoforder to update in explicit interface and sqldata does not contain a definition for account list etc

Comment: Is it possible to add this code into the sap business 1 configuration and it would compare addresses and if it matches the bp master data and if it doesnt it gives you that error popup?

Comment: Hi are there any updates?

Comment: you say you have code in your visual studio that will update addresses, you need to post this code in it's entirety. I am worried you are performing database updates via SQL commands which could potentially corrupt your installation and invalidate your support.

Comment: Yes i posted the code in its entirety, but i didnt use it and only used the b1 validation configuration

Comment: you say "So I have code which is linked to the SAP Business Partner Master Data which can update the addresses from my visual studio."  no where is this code posted. None of the code in your question will update anything.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Im not trying to update anything. Im just trying to make comparisons

Comment: the literal title of your question has the word update in it.